# How to start spring application even if Kafka listener (spring-kafka) doesn't initialize

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm working on an application that uses a Kafka listener using spring-kafka. The problem I'm facing is that the spring context initialization fails when the Kafka listener doesn't turn on (Various reasons, such as Kafka server is not turned on or is down). How can I make sure that my application is independent.

Can anyone please help.

Comment: profile based configuration? if profile is kafka, kafka based configurations start?

Comment: I'm not using profile based. I'm using environmental variables to control the Kafka configuration.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is because the kafka server belongs to a different project and I'm one of their clients. In case they have their kafka server down, I don't want our application to go down.

Comment: so you already used variables to control it ? if not use @ConditionalOnProperty based configuration

Comment: oh so you want to do some health check on kafka before you start the application ?

Comment: Yes Barath. That's what I'm looking for. Also in case the Kafka fails to start, I don't want my application to fail start (context not able to initialize due to bean not able to initialize).

Comment: it is bit tricky, Lets hear it from the experts. My opinion is to use profile based configuration. you can use  @Lazy to skip the bean initilaization during startup for kafka configuration but still is it right ? I am not sure.

Comment: Problem with lazy is that I should find a means to activate kafka on multiple instances of my application in time of need and it feels more messier.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Set `autoStartup(false)` on the container factory.

Inject (e.g. `@Autowired`) the `KafkaListenerEndpointRegistry` and `start()` it in your code (in a try/catch).

You can also start/stop containers individually by getting them from the registry (using the `@KafkaListener` `id`).

Comment: Thanks Gary. I will check this solution and update my observations.

Comment: Only issue, I had is that I have to use some sort of dummy name as topic name for Kafka listener. Seems like there is a null check imposed on the that.